# Cannot pass down selected User from drop down menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like admins to be able to add users to an existing organization via a drop down menu. However, I cannot successfully pass the selected user to the method.

I can confirm the path is correct but it can never find the selected user id.

**Controller Method**

```
 def add
   @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])

   if request.post?
     @user = User.find params[:id]
     @organization.users << @user
   end
 end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for @organization, url: organization_add_path(@organization), 
                            html: { method: :add } do |f| %>
   <%= f.select :id, User.order('first_name ASC').map{|u| [u.name, u.id]}, 
       { include_blank: '-Users-' }, class: "drop-down" %>
   <%= f.submit "Add user", class: "primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The error returned is `Couldn't find User without an ID` highlighting the line `@user = User.find params[:id]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the logs of your rails server, there you will see the params hash that is holding the information from the form and the url.
It will look something like this:

```
params = {organization: {user_id: 2}, ...}
```

The user id is gathered in the from so most likely it will be under the `organization` key in the params hash.
So you should be able to retrieve it like this:

```
@user = User.find(params[:organization][:id])
```